# Available macros for Titanium Module development

Tags: ios, macros, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-modules

I'm working on some modules for Titanium based iOS application.

I found some useful macros like:

```
ENSURE_SINGLE_ITEM(args,type)    - for type casting
ENSURE_UI_THREAD_0_ARGS          - for running the function on main thread
ENSURE_UI_THREAD_1(arg)          - for running the function on main thread with argument
```

These macros helped me a lot in module  development.

I'm interested to know that is there any other macros available for these kind of purposes ?

I searched a lot but, and got some more like:

```
NUMINT      - Equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithInt:value]

NUMBOOL     - Equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithInt:value]

NUMLONG     - Equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithLong:value]

NUMLONGLONG - Equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:value]

NUMDOUBLE   - Equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithDouble:value]

NUMFLOAT    - Equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithFloat:value]
```

Is there any other such macros available ? Where can I find the documentation of these macros ?

Answer (score 0):

`ENSURE_UI_THREAD_1(arg)` is another.

Search for "macro" on the iOS dev guide. All of those you pointed out, plus the one I pointed out, are there.

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/iOS+Module+Development+Guide